# Missing words? In *my* crossword?

Tags: cryptic-crosswords

[image]

Some clues are missing one of four different five-letter words, marked **A**, **B**, **C** and **D**. The missing words are included in the grid as the unclued entries **16a**, **35a**, **22d** and **23d**, not necessarily in that order. Find the missing words and fill the grid.

**Across**
1. Performs surveillance with zero seconds to go (7)
6. **A**'s trial finally ended (5)
9. 36 down donated a plant (5)
11. Trainer at sea or land (7)
12. Things **B** together for poor gal in care of retired mother (7)
13. Game #4 of Cards Against Humanity (5)
14. Way to end someone's marriage, at last: promptly running in the opposite direction (5)
15. Extortion case – bringing of charges following (7)
16. *(unclued)*
19. Innocent child singer has unopened **C** to start with (6)
23. Two Egyptian gods; second returns to initial state (6)
26. Not running by a river in Spanish province (7)
27. Follower of Chinese leader facing very strong American in revolution (6)
28. Yours truly is aboard, masculine at **D** (6)
29. The day before getting left with American, I became evasive (7)
30. Help blockading soldier, maybe **A** (6)
32. Pirate captain's lost his head, **D** and stomach, say (6)
35. *(unclued)*
38. One may bite hard **C**, occasionally, inspiring twisted ditty (7)
40. **D** perhaps experiencing top luxury accommodation: ... (5)
41. … A mountain hotel with a bit of atmosphere (5)
42. Catalogue **C**, old bigwig (7)
43. Vehicles having rough interior for those looking for a young **A** (7)
44. Strange beverage, unopened and **B** evenly (5)
45. Bury woman passed in the cold part of the year (5)
46. Attracts crowd, ultimately with vulgar wickedness (5,2)

**Down**
1. One hundred support a divine being that's magnificient (8)
2. Singing above the peaks of Kiwis' "Everest" – amazing, endless Aoraki (7)
3. Address monitor at empty **C** (5)
4. Two people, together, met and… fooled around (6)
5. In Italy, three **C** essentially placed under mother's rectangular arrangement (6)
6. Rented out to the minimum extent, they say (6)
7. Small bottles; volume is about one litre (5)
8. Music newspaper and magazine (7)
10. First person **B** game's icons (6)
17. Break in to be in rebellion, united around **A** (7)
18. Nobleman that's head of region, until now (7)
20. Nation south of **D** of 30 down (5)
21. Umpire has it put back into place (5)
22. *(unclued)*
23. *(unclued)*
24. After drinking whiskey, perform vocal jazz (5)
25. Claw of vertically sizable individual scratching feet (5)
30. Sarah flying above a desert (6)
31. Gin, a little Noilly-Prat and finally bitter, **B**, with orange peel? (7)
33. I'm captured by extremely orderly guards – ultimately, 38 and 42 across? (7)
34. Tests on **B** headwear (7)
35. *Listener* solver's last pieces written down by **D**, mostly (6)
36. Adam Banks, father in Marseille, became one of France's foremost scientists (6)
37. Detected time **A** performed exceptionally well (6)
39. A little piece of information of New Year's festival at company retreat (5)
40. Diving below the surface of small island in the Caribbean (5)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The solved grid:

> [image]

Clue explanations:

> [image]